# Filtering tabular data with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a little help to put me in the right direction. This is what I am trying to achieve.

I have a table of data e.g.

```
<table><thead>
<tr><th>Categories</th><th>Week 1</th><th>Week 2</th><th>Week 3</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>Category 1</td>
    <td>Sam: 5 <br /> Roger 10</td>
    <td>Sam: 0 <br /> Roger 5</td>
    <td>Susan: 25 <br /> Aimee 15</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>Category 2</td>
    <td>Sam: 5 <br /> John: 15</td>
    <td>Sam: 0 <br /> Roger: 15</td>
    <td>Susan: 25 <br /> Aimee: 15</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

These are the users who have number assigned in the table above.

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">John</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Roger</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Aimee</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sam</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Susan</a></li>
</ul>
```

I was hoping to create a filter using JQuery so that if I wanted to see John only in the table above I would click against that name in the list above. I have complete control over the markup so I can wrap user names in the table with required classes (for selecting) or add any additional code etc.

How do I achieve that? I have limited experience using Jquery so any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why You are Not using Data Table for filtering?

Comment: Each cell has multiple values in there .. so if it was one column of one username per cell then yes that would make sense to use data table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

modified HTML:

```
<ul class="names">
<li><a href="#">John</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Roger</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Aimee</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sam</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Susan</a></li>
</ul>

<table><thead>
<tr><th>Categories</th><th>Week 1</th><th>Week 2</th><th>Week 3</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>Category 1</td>
    <td><span data-name="Sam">Sam: 5</span> <br /> <span data-name="Roger">Roger 10</span></td>
    <td><span data-name="Sam">Sam: 0</span> <br /> <span data-name="Roger">Roger 5</span></td>
    <td><span data-name="Susan">Susan: 25</span> <br /> <span data-name="Aimee">Aimee 15</span></td>
</tr>
<tr><td>Category 2</td>
    <td><span data-name="Sam">Sam: 5</span> <br /> <span data-name="John">John: 15</span></td>
    <td><span data-name="Sam">Sam: 0</span> <br /> <span data-name="Roger">Roger: 15</span></td>
    <td><span data-name="Susan">Susan: 25</span> <br /> <span data-name="Aimee">Aimee: 15</span></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

js Code:

```
$(".names a").click(function(){
  $("table span[data-name]").hide();
  $("table span[data-name='"+$(this).text()+"']").show();
});
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1bh7ue49/1/

Comment: Yes works well! I just need to add to show all options. I am wondering what's the difference in yours and caramba answers (other than ^) ? Thx

Comment: You deleted your answer @caramba?

Comment: @Caramba: Deleting your answer was not necassary. I first did not saw your `^=`. :) I will take your part of code to my answer, ok?

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML, just wrap your player names in a span and proceed further.

JS:

```
function begin(){
  $('a').on('click', function(){
    let $span = $('span');
    $span.show();
    const player = $(this).text().trim();
    $span.each((i, s) => {
      if($(s).text().indexOf(player) === -1){
        $(s).hide();
      }
    });
  });

}

$(document).ready(begin);
```

HTML:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Categories</th>
      <th>Week 1</th>
      <th>Week 2</th>
      <th>Week 3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Category 1</td>
      <td>
        <span>Sam: 5</span>
        <br />
        <span>Roger 10</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span>Sam: 0</span>
        <br />
        <span>Roger 5</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span>Susan: 25</span>
        <br />
        <span>Aimee 15</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Category 2</td>
      <td>
        <span>Sam: 5</span>
        <br />
        <span>John: 15</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span>Sam: 0</span>
        <br />
        <span>Roger: 15</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span>Susan: 25</span>
        <br />
        <span>Aimee: 15</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<ul>
  <li><a href="#">John</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Roger</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Aimee</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Sam</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Susan</a></li>
</ul>
```

[DEMO](https://codepen.io/SweetCodingInc/pen/xrLLJq?editors=1010)

Comment: Yes it works. I have got 3 answers resolving my issue. I need to mark one as my answer now. I'll have a play about with all the options and see. Thanks